# How to push individual (optional) parameters into an array

Tags: arrays, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to populate an array (`fruit.Price`)with properties supplied in the first `WITH` line of the following cypher code:

```
WITH [{Price_1:15,Price_2:20,Price_3:17,strFruit:"apples"},{Price_1:2,Price_2:1,Price_3:1.5,Price_4:3,strFruit:"pears"}] AS props
UNWIND props as p
MATCH (fruit:Fruit) WHERE fruit.strFruit=p.strFruit
FOREACH (price in [p.Price_1,p.Price_2,p.Price_3,p.Price_4] |SET fruit.Price = fruit.Price + price) 
RETURN fruit
```

where the maximum quantity of `p.Price_`n is 4, but not all are necessarily supplied (as above, where p.Price_4 is missing in the first row).  These properties will always be supplied consecutively i.e. Price_4 won't be supplied without Price_3 also.

How do I populate an array with a variable number of elements in this way?  For what it's worth; I'm actually using the HTTP Rest API and the WITH line is in reality a `parameters:` command.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `coalesce()`, and default to 0 for the ones that don't exist. Also, it might be easier to do `reduce()` instead of `foreach()`. (Updated to use CASE/WHEN instead of coalesce.)

Even easier would be to pass in an array of variable length `{prices:[15,20,17], strFruit:"apples"}`... or just the total price (if you have control over that).

```
WITH [{Price_1:15,Price_2:20,Price_3:17,strFruit:"apples"},{Price_1:2,Price_2:1,Price_3:1.5,Price_4:3,strFruit:"pears"}] AS props
UNWIND props as p
MATCH (fruit:Fruit) WHERE fruit.strFruit=p.strFruit
SET fruit.Price = reduce(total = [], price in [p.Price_1,p.Price_2,p.Price_3,p.Price_4] | CASE WHEN NOT price is NULL THEN total + price ELSE total END) 
RETURN fruit
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/o69bii

Comment: Thanks Wes, but that's not quite what I'm after.  I need an array of the prices, rather than the sum of them.  So for the first row `fruit.Price[15,20,17]` and for the second row `fruit.Price[2,1,1.5,3]`.  I'm unable to pass in an array.